# How to add two decimal variables in MASM x86 and output the sum

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am very new to MASM and assembly, and I am writing my first program. I am having trouble figuring out how to add two variables together and output the result. Here is part of my program so far:

```
 INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

 .data
 firstNum   DWORD   ?
 secondNum  DWORD   ?   
 sum        DWORD   ?       

 .code
 main PROC

 ;Get Data

 call      ReadInt
 mov       firstNum, eax
 call      ReadInt
 mov       secondNum, ebx

 ;Calculate Sum

 mov       eax, firstNum
 mov       ebx, secondNum
 add       eax, ebx
 mov       sum, eax

 ;Display Results 

 mov       eax, sum
 call      WriteDec
```

When I run this code, it outputs some long number "333420163" instead of what the sum should be, which is 7. I am still very new to this so if it's a simple answer I'm sorry haha. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know irvine, but `mov secondNum, ebx` can't be correct, if `mov    firstNum, eax` was. If "ReadInt" returns the read value into EAX, the 2nd move should be `mov secondNum, eax`

Comment: Thank you, I was confused because I thought that if I moved the secondNum into eax it would replace the first variable. I'm still not quite sure how these registers work. It worked after I did what said!

Comment: "mov" works the other way round. if you write "mov variable, eax" then eax's content is moved INTO this memory, not FROM there ;-)
Obviously "ReadInt" retuns the value in EAX, after storing this value in firstNum, EAX is free to be used again

Comment: Awesome! If I knew this site was so easy to get answers from helpful people like you I would have been asking questions ages ago haha

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger, as well.  Executing your code step by step in a debugger would have allowed you to find the answer to your question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

On most x86 ABIs, return values for functions are typically in the `EAX` register, and, in the case that a return value is 64-bits long, instead of 32-bits, the upper 32-bits will be in the `EDX` register.

Your instructions:

```
call      ReadInt
mov       secondNum, ebx
```

Are not getting the return value from the second call to `ReadInt` because it is *not* in `EBX`; it's in `EAX`.

Replace it with `mov secondNum, eax`, because that will put the actual return value from `ReadInt` into `secondNum`.

Comment: It's even easier: if the first call to `ReadInt` returns the result in `EAX`, the second call will surely do so, too.